# How to divide with BigDecimals

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to divide `BigDecimals`, `1 / 14819.79865821543`, but the result is `0` instead of `0.00006748`

where coinRateInUSDWalletTo = 14819.79865821543 and amount = 1

```
BigDecimal numberOfCoinsToTransfer = amount.divide(
    new BigDecimal(coinRateInUSDWalletTo),
    RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Can not reproduce, please provide a [mcve], emphasis on **complete**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a `scale` for the `BigDecimal`.

```
final BigDecimal coinRateInUSDWalletTo = new BigDecimal("14819.79865821543");
final BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(
    coinRateInUSDWalletTo,
    10 /* Scale */,
    RoundingMode.HALF_UP
);
```

Note also the use of `BigDecimal.ONE`. No need to create another one (lol).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to give the scale.

Following is the declaration for **BigDecimal.divide()** method.

> public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode
>   roundingMode)

If you specify scale 8 then you will get your desired answer: `0.00006748`

```
 BigDecimal numberOfCoinsToTransfer = amount.divide(new BigDecimal 
 (coinRateInUSDWalletTo),8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```